# How can I get the version information of mongodb through pymongo or other python tools?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

As the title. It seems that pymongo does not support, is there any other easy way to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you are connected to your MongoDB via pymongo you can retrieve the version with:

```
db.command({'buildInfo':1})['version']
```

This would return e.g. `'4.4.5'`.

Answer (score 6):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(uri)

version = client.server_info()["version"]
version_array = client.server_info()["versionArray"]

print(version)
>>> '4.4.4'
print(version_array)
>>> [4, 4, 4, 0]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.